# iOs SDK. Shared audio session while playin background audio

Tags: ios, audio

I'm faced with very interesting problem and now I'm trying to understand how to sort it out. In fact, my application plays sound when it come into background. Everything is ok, but when I run application like youtube it make interuption for my audio session. I use audio session delegate methods to catch this moment. My question is that how to restore my audio session in background after I kill youtube?
I've tried this:

```
NSError *err = noErr; 
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &err]; 
if(err != noErr) 
{ 
    NSLog([err description]); 
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as I understood, to make audio session mixed with other application I have to set special property like this:

```
UInt32 allowMixing = true;

AudioSessionSetProperty ( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,  
                          sizeof (allowMixing),                                 
                          &allowMixing                                          
                        );
```

And now I can see that my application plays audio in background even if I start youtube. The problem is that it plays audio simultaneously :(. I can hear my application's audio and youtube as well. There is not audio session interruption. Strange problem.

Comment: This is deprecated now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682502/audiosessionsetproperty-deprecated-in-ios-7-0-so-how-set-kaudiosessionproperty-o