# AudioSessionSetProperty deprecated in iOS 7.0 so how set kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Need non deprecated alternate to (btw I think this is still in the current apple docs at [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW35)):

```
OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
UInt32 allowMixing = true;

propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                       kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,  // 1
                       sizeof (allowMixing),                                 // 2
                       &allowMixing                                          // 3
                   );
```

Thanks;

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `AVAudioSession`:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
if (![session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
         withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
         error:&setCategoryError]) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks,this appears to accomplish the same thing.  I am a little confused when the deprecated way of doing this seems to imply an OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers is being set though.

Comment: you'll need to do @import AVFoundation;