# What is the best microphone recording settings for AVAudio?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

So I have the current code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //for recording audio
    _stopButton.enabled = NO;
    _playButton.hidden = true;

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recording.caf"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh], AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:128000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                        error:nil];

    _audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                      initWithURL:soundFileURL
                      settings:recordSettings
                      error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    }
    //----------------------------
    //end

}
```

---

And the player:

```
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    [_playButton setEnabled:NO];
    if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        _stopButton.enabled = YES;
        _recordButton.enabled = NO;

        NSError *error;

        _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfURL:_audioRecorder.url
                        error:&error];
        _audioPlayer.volume = 5;
        _audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [_audioPlayer play];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"errormax");
    }
}
```

I have the `_audioPlayer.volume` at `5` because any lower you can barely here it. But it peeks and sounds extremely distorted at that volume. Why can it not sound like "Voice Memos" where it plays it back at a reasonable volume without it distorting?

What are the best quality settings for this?

Comment: In `AVAudioPlayer.h`: `@property float volume; /* The volume for the sound. The nominal range is from 0.0 to 1.0. */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personaly prefer PCM encoding, I've had better quality using it.

try:

```
NSDictionary *recordSettings = 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
nil];
```

or to make it more readable:

```
NSDictionary * recordSetting;
recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

Adjust your function like this:

```
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    [_playButton setEnabled:NO];
    if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        _stopButton.enabled = YES;
        _recordButton.enabled = NO;

        //force the session to play to come out of speakers!
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
        UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);

        NSError *error;

        _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfURL:_audioRecorder.url
                        error:&error];
        _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [_audioPlayer play];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"errormax");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The playback is still very quiet though @meda

Comment: oh so the problem is playing the sound, not the recoring? @Maximilian

Comment: yes. I thought it was due to the recording quality. But it just seems to be to do with the `_audioPlayer.volume` ?

Comment: @Maximilian, I havent done this in a while, if you are really concernn, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684014/1880431 `;)`

Comment: @meda - is it possible to record and play together. I am recording from bluetooth headset via bluetooth and able to play on iphone speaker but after stopped recording. I want to do it simultaneously.  What u say ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of audio session category "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord". It always play audio in receiver unless you explicitly change the overrideOutputAudioPort. You may have to add listener for AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification to change the category based on your out put. Anyway why this headache, just use AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord before you start recording and  AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback before you start  player.

//Player

```
 newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
```

//Recorder

```
newRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:fileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error: &setCategoryError];
```