# AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers) deprecated

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, avaudiosession

I used

```
 UInt32 doSetProperty = 0;
    OSStatus status1 = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);
```

I saw that it become deprecated and I changed it with:

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
              withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                    error:&setCategoryError]) {
    // handle error
}
```

After doing that, the `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` is not called any longer.

In both version I did:

```
success &= [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

Did anyone encounter this kind of problem?

Comment: Please check this link..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684014/3378413

Comment: Already did. I checked from the deprecated one to the new version, but the event is not triggered anymore when new way is used.

Answer (score -1):

Did you import AVFoundation?

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and did you forget to set delegate?

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Comment: This is phrased like clarification questions and should hence be a comment. If you intend it to answer the question please avoid rhetoric questions and add more explanation of why this is relevant and how it is supposed to solve the problem.